# Change Navigation Drawer with a single image

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation menu in my app and I want to have both the Nav header(containing the profile) and the NavigationView(containing item lists) to both have the same background. Something like this:
[image]

I can apply different backgrounds to the NavHeader and NavigationView, but how can I have just one background for all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use root layout and put header and NavigationView as the child of it.
child layout has the transparent background and root layout has the background. @Bryan Ibrahim

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just removed the background on the nav_header_home.xml and left the background on the NavigationView, this fills the whole NavigationDrawer with the same image.